# How to set background image in Flet (Flutter) in Python

Tags: python, flutter, flet

Can anyone help me in this problem? I want set the background image of a flet app (frameless)
The results must look like this:

## Before

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGA9Z.png)

## After (Expectations)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQcgZ.jpg)

I was in hurry so this is not properly edited.
(I don't have much repuations in this StackOverflow Account So I can't attach image directly)
I tried to use `ft.Container`'s `image_src` parameter but didn't work.

Comment: Try adding image inside content..